# How to add a value obtained from a dictionary to a new column in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file `list1.csv` which looks like this:-

```
MVA,REG
8144801,KYB765ZP
```

I am trying to add a column to `list1.csv` so that it will look like this:

```
MVA,REG,NO
8144801,KYB765ZP,4598
```

The code `a=dict1.get(row[1])` evaluates to `4598`, so how do I add this value to the CSV file?

```
import csv

dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
list = []
list2 = []
counta = 0

with open('/Users/list2.csv') as file_handler:
    reader = csv.reader(file_handler)
    next(reader, None) # skip headerfor row in reader:
    for row in reader:
        key = row[1]
        counta += 1
        #print(key)
        if key in dict1.keys():
            list.append(key)
        else:
            dict1[row[1]] = counta

with open('/Users/list1.csv') as file_handler:
    reader = csv.reader(file_handler)
    next(reader, None) # skip headerfor row in reader:
    for row in reader:
        key = row[1]
        #print(key)
        if key in dict1.keys():
            a = dict1.get(row[1])
        else:
            list2.append(key)
```

Comment: Where is `dict1` getting it's content? Why are you reading two different .csv files? What does `list2.csv` have to do with your question?

Comment: list1.csv and list2.csv are two diiferent files which I am comparing

Comment: What do they have to do with your question. Where is your attempt to change the CSV file?

Comment: I am a novice at Python and do not know how to do it hence no attempt. If I am able to add the number I will be able to tell which entries in the two files are the same. I am just doing this as a learning exercise.

Comment: Please add an example of `list2.csv` to your question

Comment: Being a novice is no excuse for not making an attempt. You need to provide enough information for others to answer your question. It's also best to provide a [mre] that doesn't contain any code unrelated to the problem.

Comment: list2.csv is the same format  as list1.csv ie. MVA,REG 8123404,XYX8230KP

Comment: @martineau point taken I will remember this.